# Getting rotation event of UICollectionViewController inside a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, xamarin, rotation, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview

I have a `GetCell` method that returns a `UITableViewCell`, and inside this I want to add my `UICollectionViewController`, however the only way I could get it to display anything was to add the `UICollectionView` from the controller to the cell.

This seemed fine to do until I am trying to add the `ViewWillLayoutSubviews()` method to my `UICollectionViewController` to detect and resize the layout when the device rotates. My problem is that this `ViewWillLayoutSubviews()` method never gets called.

It does however get called when I put it on my class that inherits from `UITableView`. I can't do my logic here though as I need to change the width and height of my `UICollectionViewCells`.

Any help with resizing the `UICollectionViewCells` or improving how I add the `UICollectionViewController` to the `UITableViewCell` would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

My `GetCell()` Method:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tv)
{
    UITableViewCell cell = tv.DequeueReusableCell(CellKey);

    if (cell == null)
    {
        cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, CellKey);                
    }

    UICollectionView collectionView = tileController.CollectionView;       
    cell.ContentView.AddSubview(collectionView);

    return cell;
}
```

My `ViewWillLayoutSubviews` inside my `UICollectionViewController` (Never gets called though):

```
public override void ViewWillLayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.ViewWillLayoutSubviews();

        nfloat mySectionInset = 20f;
        nfloat myMinSpacing = 20f;

        var screenWidth = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width;
        nfloat defaultTileWidth;

        UICollectionViewFlowLayout flowLayout = Layout as UICollectionViewFlowLayout;
        switch (UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarOrientation)
        {
            case UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft:
            case UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight:
                defaultTileWidth = (screenWidth - (mySectionInset * 3) - myMinSpacing) / 3;
                flowLayout.ItemSize = new CGSize(defaultTileWidth, defaultTileWidth * 0.65f);
                break;
            case UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait:
            case UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown:
                defaultTileWidth = (screenWidth - (mySectionInset * 2) - myMinSpacing) / 2;
                flowLayout.ItemSize = new CGSize(defaultTileWidth, defaultTileWidth * 0.65f);
                break;
        }

        Layout.InvalidateLayout();
    }
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're using a `UICollectionViewController` instead of just using a `UICollectionView` and overriding the `LayoutSubviews` method of the `UICollectionView`? If you really need to use the view controller version, you need to properly add it as a child view controller: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH11-SW1 and checkout the Implementing a Custom Container View Controller section.

Comment: Alternatively, I also think you could implement this entirely in your `UITableViewController` by accessing the visible cells using `UITableView. IndexPathsForVisibleRows` and then grab each cell using `UITableView.GetCell` and then have the cell modify its contents. Lastly, I think `ViewWillTransitionToSize` is a more common approach to monitoring rotation and size change events in a view controller.